# KVO for dependent property depending on itself

Tags: iphone, cocoa, dependency-properties, key-value-observing

I've defined two properties with corresponding ivars and synthesized them:

```
@property (nonatomic,copy) NSString* title;
@property (nonatomic,copy) NSString* person;
```

Now in my implementation, I've the following custom getter for `title`:

```
- (NSString*)title {
    return (person) ? person : [title capitalizedString];
}
```

So the `title` property depends on both the `title` property itself and the `person` property. I'd like to make this class KVO compatible, so I added:

```
+ (NSSet*)keyPathsForValuesAffectingTitle {
    return [NSSet setWithObjects:@"person", nil];
}
```

Now my question: Do I have to add `@"title"` to the set as well, to make sure changes of the `title` property are observed, too? If yes, doesn't this create an infinite loop?

Or does KVO automatically depend on the property itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the docs, you don't put the 'title' property in the set. I presume it's assumed that all properties are, by default, dependent upon themselves.